# Right translation with regard to modus and tempus of "should have been"

Tags: anglais, temps-grammatical

I'd like to translate:

> 5 datasets should have been imported. Of those 3 datasets could'nt be linked to a certain file and therefore were ignored.

This is my translation:

> 5 ensembles de données ont du être importés, dont 3 ensembles de données 
>   étaient impossibles à lier avec un cas et étaient rejetés.

I'm not too sure whether I kept the right tempus and modus of this first part:

> 5 datasets should have been imported

with that translation:

> 5 ensembles de données ont du être importés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion :

> 5 jeux de données auraient du être importés. Parmi ceux-ci, 3 n'ont pas pu être liés à un fichier et ont donc été ignorés.

Comment: Le participe passé de « devoir » prend un circonflexe : « auraient **dû** être ».

Answer (score 4):

- “datasets” → “***jeux*** de données” (Here *jeux* means “sets”, “collections”, not “games”)
- “should have been imported” → “***auraient*** dû être importés”
  *ont dû être importés* would mean “had to be imported”. Using the conditional mood turns the obligation into a recommendation.
- The past participle of *devoir* is ***dû***; *du* is the (mandatory) contraction of *de le*.
- The past participle *importé**s*** is a complement of the auxiliary *être*, so it agrees with the subject, which is plural.
- Regarding the tense of the second clause, there's a possible choice between the imperfect (*imparfait*) and the past perfect (*passé composé*). They have overlapping but not always identical meanings.

  - An *imparfait* implies a statement that was true at any point in time, or at least for a long length of time.
    “*ne pouvaient être liés à un certain fichier*”
    “*étaient impossibles à lier à un certain fichier*”
  - A *passé composé* states that the fact was true at a specific point in the past, when the attempt was made. It doesn't imply anything as to whether another attempt might have succeeded.
    “*n'ont pas pu être liés à un certain fichier*”
    “*ont été impossibles à lier à un certain fichier*”
    “*se sont avéré impossibles à lier à un certain fichier*” (more formal than “*ont été*”; an English equivalent (without the formal aspect) would be “turned out to be …”)
- In French, we wouldn't repeat “datasets”. (Your sentence is clumsy in English as well.) Possibilities include:

  - “***Parmi ceux-ci***, trois n'ont pas pu …”
  - “***Trois d'entre eux*** n'ont pas pu …”
  - “*Cinq jeux de données auraient dû être importés, **parmi lesquels** trois n'ont pas pu …*” (This is a little clumsy because “*parmi lesquels*” is far from its antecedent “*cinq jeux de données*”, but French people do write like this.)
- “*impossibles **à** lier*” — *à* is the preposition, *a* is the form of the verb *avoir*.
- “a certain file” → “*un certain fichier*”, here a direct translation is appropriate. *Cas* may be a better word though, but if so *case* would probably be a better word in English as well.
- “were ignored” → “***ont été*** omis”
  Here the *imparfait* is not possible, because the processing of the datasets (presumably) happened once, it wasn't going on continuously.
- Regarding the choice of verb to translate *ignored*, there's no exact equivalent to this verb in French:

  - ***Omis*** means “omitted”, “skipped”.
  - *Ignorés* is a false friend and cannot be used here. *Ignorer* means not knowing something, or deliberately not paying attention to something; it doesn't stretch to skipping something.
  - ***Rejetés*** isn't a translation of *ignored* (it means “rejected”), but it could fit in context, if some deliberate decision was taken to omit the datasets.
  - Similarly, ***exclus*** is not an exact translation but could fit.
  - There are other possibilities that use a negation: “*… et **n'**‍ont **pas** été **inclus***”, “*… et **n'**‍ont **pas** été **pris en compte***”, “*… et **n'**‍ont **pas** été **retenus***”, …

*Cinq jeux de données auraient dû être importés. Trois d'entre eux n'ont pas pu être liés à un certain fichier et ont donc été omis.*

Comment: +1 pour les explications. Petite suggestion acquise au fil de mon expérience personnelle : commencer par une réponse générale (et la mettre en évidence), puis aller dans le détail (je commence généralement par un TL;DR). C'est également une bonne pratique journalistique (donner les grands éléments puis aller dans le détail). Ainsi, le lecteur peut trouver ce dont il a besoin et choisir de descendre plus bas s'il le souhaite, sans avoir à miner au cœur d'une réponse peut-être plus détaillée que son besoin pour extraire la pépite (ne serait-ce que pour ceux qui liront cette question à l'avenir).

Answer (score 1):

The right translation would be :

> 5 ensembles de données **auraient du être** importés. **Parmi ceux-ci,** 3 **n'ont pas pu être liés** avec un **certain fichier** et **ont donc été ignorés**

Explanations:

1. the tense of "should have been imported". Because "ont du être importé" means "had to be imported", which is not the same thing.
2. "a certain file" = "un certain fichier". Saying this looks odd, but it is the same thing in english...
3. ignored != rejected

Comment: Réponse correcte à la question principale, mais il reste quelques erreurs : orthographe de *dû*, contresens sur *ignorer* (c'est un faux ami, alors que *rejeté* ne convient pas si mal dans ce contexte), traduction trop mot-à-mot de *dataset*.